# CSS cascading priority

Tags: css, html, class

I've got this HTML that I'm trying to style:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <menu id="menubarTransportControls">Foobar</menu>
</div>
```

Can anyone explain why this CSS...

```
#menubar menu {
    width: auto;
}
```

...takes priority over...

```
#menubarTransportControls {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm using IE7 with the HTML5 shiv javascript. Thanks

Comment: have you placed the css for menu later to the id? can you try reversing the declaration?

Comment: @sudimail: Just for your information: the order only matters when selectors have equal specificity, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#menubar menu` has higher specificity than `#menubarTransportControls`.

To understand specificity:

- The specs: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity
- If you like Star Wars: http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html
- Otherwise: http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

You can use this calculator if you like:

http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php

```
Selector                    Score (a,b,c,d)
#menubar menu               0,1,0,1
#menubarTransportControls   0,1,0,0
```

Be sure to read some of the above resources to understand what the "Score" means.

Comment: +1 - just to clarify the obvious for the OP, specificity overrides the Cascade, i.e. it won't matter what order they are in the sheet being more specific rules!

Answer (score 1):

Because `#menubar menu` is more specific than `#menubarTransportControls`

See for more info http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

it's all about the priory. In css `id` is more powerful then `class & element` for example

`id=100`

```
class=10
element=1
```

so in your example :

```
#menubar menu = 100 + 1 = 101
```

&

```
#menubarTransportControls = 100 = 100
```

so which one is more powreful. for more check this http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/ (CSS Presentation)

Comment: not going to vote down, as the answer is **specificity** and the concept is here, but specificity is not as simple as adding the numbers, (though unless you have more than 9 elements in the selector it'll work) - see [@thirtydot's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264084/quick-css-cascading-question/6264148#6264148) - posted prior to yours for the right way to count it

Comment: i am only describe what radbourm3 has ask & for more i giving the link.

Answer (score 0):

`#menubar menu` is calling directly the `menu` tag so it takes priority.